# Issue executing shell file on Mac OS

Tags: laravel, react-native, shell, sh

I'm new to Mac OS, I have a `.sh` file that contains a few instructions to startup Laravel server, React Native Metro server, ngrok etc.

When I execute with :

```
bash /Users/username/Desktop/proyectos/wooloveapp.com/laravelapp/scripts/app-startup-mac.sh
```

I get the following error:

```
The file /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com/laravelappcom/scripts/cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan serve does not exist.
The file /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com/laravelappcom/scripts/cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan db:drop && php artisan db:create && php artisan migrate --seed does not exist.
The file /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com/laravelappcom/scripts/ngrok http 8000 does not exist.
The file /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com/laravelappcom/scripts/cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/woo && cd android  && gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android -- --reset-cache does not exist.
The file /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com/laravelappcom/scripts/cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan websockets:serve does not exist.
```

**My script is simple, the locations are exact, for each line I want to open a terminal and execute the following actions on that same terminal**, is there anything I'm doing wrong?

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

open -a Terminal "cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan serve"

open -a Terminal "cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan db:drop && php artisan db:create && php artisan migrate --seed"

open -a Terminal "ngrok http 8000"

open -a Terminal "cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/woo && cd android  && gradlew clean && cd .. && npx react-native run-android -- --reset-cache"

open -a Terminal "cd /Users/gabriel/Desktop/proyectos/laravelapp.com && php artisan websockets:serve"
```

Comment: ...as the linked duplicates say, you need to pass the name of a script that contains your command, not the command itself. It's unfortunate, but that's Apple; anything noninteractive is an afterthought.